# Checking whether a game board is full

Tags: performance, scala

I have a method in Scala that checks if a game board is full or not. To speed this method up, I return inside the nested for loop to break out of both of them and stop execution. How would I achieve this in Scala in an idiomatic way?

```
def isFull: Boolean = {
  for (x <- getGrid.indices) {
    for (y <- getGrid(x).indices) {
      if (getGrid(x)(y).getState.isInstanceOf[Undecided]) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `forall` to most containers to test if every element in the container satisfies some property. `forall` will only evaluate `x + 1` if `x` is true. This type of evaluation is known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So basically we can use this property to perform the same behavior as the `if-then` statement in the original code.

Notice also that I've used pattern matching to get rid of the `isInstanceOf[T]`.

```
def isFull: Boolean =
  getGrid.indices.forall(x =>
    getGrid(x).indices.forall(y =>
      getGrid(x)(y).getState match {
        case xyState: Undecided => False
        case _ => True
      }
    )
  )
```

Comment: How does this compare speed-wise to my solution? Scala 2.10 if it matters.

Comment: Whoops I forgot to mention it, but yes, `forall` will return as soon as it encounters a false.

Comment: So they are (or should be) equally fast.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that pattern matching statement a bit? `Undecided` is a `sealed trait` and I want to check if it is a sub class or not.

Comment: I've updated my answer